# ¿que es el hospedaje web en la nube?

Tags: web

buenas tardes. he investigado sobre el hospedaje web en la nube pero todavía no lo tengo bien en claro. así que quería preguntar: ¿Cómo funciona el hospedaje web en la nube? gracias!!

Comment: Aquí en SO resolvemos problemas concretos de programación. Lo más probable es que este tipo de preguntas terminen cerradas. Una simple búsqueda en Google puede resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hola germanchelo, bienvenido, como te comenta Xedrian, tu pregunta no encaja con los lineamientos del sitio, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que la gente llama "la nube" es solo un servidor dedicado que nunca se apaga, una CPU siempre encendida que "sirve" el servicio de alojamiento para tus datos. Ese tipo de servicio estaria siendo ofrecido por empresas que tienen una estructura fisica de servidores y te venden espacio en un disco y recursos como RAM y CPU. Como es caro tener esa infraestructura, te sale mas barato "rentarlo" que es lo que al final se acuerda en un plazo fijo de tiempo por una cuota.